# Poner variables en texto plano

Tags: laravel, variables

Hola buenas tardes disculpen como puedo poner una variable de Laravel de algun modelo en un texto plano por ejemplo:

```
$mensaje->cuerpomensaje
```

tiene este mensaje por defecto

```
Hola [usuario] te damos la bienvenida.
```

Como puedo hacer para que en el `[usuario]` aparezca el nombre del usuario por ejemplo logeado o el nombre de algún otro usuario que yo elija.

Comment: Listo gracias igual ya encontre una solucion viable saludos

Comment: Si encontraste la solución compártela con la comunidad, eso ayudará a muchos otros que afronten el mismo problema.

Comment: str_replace(['[Usuario]','[mensaje]','[candidato]' ], [$user->name, 'perro', ''], $correo->mensaje) gracias por la respuesta esta fue la solucion que encontre soy nuevo en este foro jajaj estare mucho mas al pendiente saludos.!

Comment: genial, pero publicalo en la parte de abajo como una respuesta para ayudar a otros, léete [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la función [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de php para dividir tu cuerpo del mensaje quitando el texto de muestra y luego unir los elementos del array que te genera con el dato que deseas, por ejemplo el nombre del usuario logeado:

```
$string = explode("[usuario]", $mensaje->cuerpomensaje);

$texto_a_mostrar = $string[0] . auth()->user()->name . $string[1];

// Hola Karloz Eduardo te damos la bienvenida
```

Comment: También se podría usar un implode `echo implode(auth()->user()->name, $string);` pero me parece que siendo Laravel, usar Blade es mas conveniente para esos casos

Comment: Cierto @aloMalbarez, corregido

Comment: muchas gracias por responder lo solucione de esta manera str_replace(['[Usuario]','[mensaje]','[candidato]' ], [$user->name, 'hola a todos', ''], $correo->mensaje) con un str_replace dentre de la plantilla de blade